# bodyParser is striked out cannot POST error in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code, calculator

[My instructor's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq6PZ.png)

and this is my code but the var named bodyParser is striked out i don't know why and my calculator is not working saying cannot POST /index.html this calculator is used to add just two numbers
here is my code

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afnit.png)

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(<strike>**bodyParser**</strike>.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
  var num1 = Number(req.body.num1);
  var num2 = Number(req.body.num2);

  var result = num1 + num2;

  res.send("the result is " + result);
});

app.listen(4040, function () {
  console.log("Server started at port 4040");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to use body-parser you have to install it first
you can do that by Hyper bash

cd <to the folder where your .js file>

npm install body-parser

check in package.json to make sure body-parser is installed

Answer (score 0):

Configure body-parser like this

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with `Express 4.16.0`, the `body-parser` is included in `Express` source, so you can remove `body-parser` package and use `Express` core module instead:

```
const express = require('express');

app.use(express.json({}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

> The express.json() and express.urlencoded() middleware have been added
> to provide request body parsing support out-of-the-box. This uses the
> expressjs/body-parser module module underneath, so apps that are
> currently requiring the module separately can switch to the built-in
> parsers.